# WebMatrix WebSecurity not returning current user id

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cordova, razor, webmatrix

I have two requests created by the same $.ajax request but one is from Google Chrome the other is on a PhoneGap application. The WebMatrix application should return the id of the user that has submitted their username and password credentials (PS: that's not the point of the application but it's simplified for the sake of this question).

The browser based request works but PhoneGap doesn't. Do you know why? I have included the Chrome request headers but I can't get my hands on the complete PhoneGap application's headers.

I have found a work around for this but it REALLY bugs me that it doesn't work.

WebMatrix application code

```
if(IsPost){
        var username = Request.Form["username"];
        var password = Request.Form["password"];
        var rememberMe = Request.Form["rememberMe"].AsBool();
        var credentials = false;

        if(!username.IsEmpty() && !password.IsEmpty()){
            credentials = true;
        }

        if (credentials && WebSecurity.Login(username, password, rememberMe)) {

            Response.Write(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        }
}
```

Google Chrome Request Headers breakdown -

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:105
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=XXXXXXX
Host:xxxxxxxxxxx
Origin:file://
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
```

Comment: Do you know the response code of the request from PhoneGap?  I'm wondering if any POSTs are getting through due to some domain policy restrictions, or if you're just getting a 500 or something.  What does your client code look like?

Comment: The response code is 200